# Adding data (string or int) to a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, type-conversion

I am trying to add data to a pre-existing char array from an int or string. Code is as follows

`int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 5;
string temp =  "Client";
char buf[64] = "This is a message for: " + temp + num1 + " " + temp + num 2;`

I appear to get conversion data errors here. I am not too sure on how to convert it correctly to the right data type. I need them to be stored into the char array as this array will then be used with `sendto()` function for UDP sockets and it is just not simply printing it out to the console/debug window

Edit: Language is c++

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: Depends a lot on the language, which you did not specify.

Comment: My mistake, language is c++. Edited main post to add this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to convert integers to strings. 
This can be done using `sprintf()`, `itoa()` or `stringstream` with operator `<<`

The second thing is to understand what operator `+` does.

```
"This is a message for: " + temp + num1 + " " + temp + num 2;
```

First will be taken first two arguments `"This is a message for: " + temp`. First argument is considerd to be a null-terminated string, second argument is an integer. There is no pre-defined operator `+` for such operation. So now no need to proceed with sum, we already failed compilation.

I can propose two solutions:

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 5;
char buf[64];
string temp = "Client";
sprintf(buf, "This is a message for: %s%d %s%d", temp.c_str(), num1, temp.c_str(), num2);
// Dangerous, can walk out of allocated memmory on the stack,
// which may not throw an exception in runtime but will mess the memory
```

And more safe

```
#include <sstream>
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 5;
string temp = "Client";
stringstream ss;
ss << "This is a message for: " << temp << num1 << " " << temp << num2;
ss.str().c_str(); // Message is here
```

Comment: I probably should have added that I need them to be stored into the char array as this array will then be used with `sendto()` function for UDP and it is just not simply printing it out to the console/debug window

Comment: No problems:
    `size_t size = ss.str().length() + 1;`
    `char* message = new char[size];`
    `memcpy(message, ss.str().c_str(), size);`
    `message[size - 1] = char(0);`


But this memory needs to be cleared afterwards or there'll be a leak.